# Executes scheduler when Quartz scheduler in different timezone

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler

My application have 3 schedulers. From that 2 having set CST timezone and other hasn't set timezone and server has UTC timezone.

I have noticed that it executes either CST timezone schedulers or UTC timezone scheduler. i.e. job A runs every day but Job B and Job c not executed as it should be.

I am not sure what was actual problem.

If anyone can help me to figure out this issue.

Here is my `global.asax` code:

```
NameValueCollection properties = null;
ISchedulerFactory sf = null;
IScheduler sched = null;
JobDetail jobDetail = null;
CronTrigger trigger = null;
properties = new NameValueCollection();
properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "RemoteServer";
properties["quartz.threadPool.type"] = "Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz";
properties["quartz.threadPool.threadCount"] = "5";
properties["quartz.threadPool.threadPriority"] = "Normal";
sf = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
sched = sf.GetScheduler();
sched.Start();

TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(Config.SchedulerTimeZone);

jobDetail = new JobDetail("JobA", "default", typeof(JobA));
trigger = new CronTrigger("JobA", "default", Config.CronExpressionJobA);
sched.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);  

jobDetail = new JobDetail("JobB", "default", typeof(JobB));
trigger = new CronTrigger("JobB", "default", Config.CronExpressionJobB);
trigger.TimeZone = timeZoneInfo;
sched.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);  //CST TimeZone

jobDetail = new JobDetail("JobC", "default", typeof(JobC));
trigger = new CronTrigger("JobC", "default", Config.CronExpressionJobC);
trigger.TimeZone = timeZoneInfo;
sched.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);  //CST TimeZone
```

Config values:

```
SchedulerTimeZone = "Central Standard Time";                
CronExpressionJobA = "0 0 6 * * ? *";               
CronExpressionJobB = "0 0 4 ? * SUN *";             
CronExpressionJobC = "0 30 4 * * ? *";
```

**Edit with example**:

i.e.

Scheduled time for jobs:
Job A: Every day at 6:00 am UTC 
Job B: 1st March at 4:00 am CST (10 am in UTC)
Job C: Every day at 4:30 am CST (10:30 am in UTC)

**Expected behavior**: All three job should be executed.

**Actual behavior**: Job A and Job C runs. But Job b doesn't.

**Possible solution:**

- Due to different schedulers time zone and it will fix with doing same time zone for all three scheduler ?
- Named Pipe binding is used to consume my Service and to initialize the scheduler we need HTTP request so This might be the issue after application pool recycle, so If we set the ping scheduler with a certain interval than it should fix this issue ?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're observing vs what you expected - your description of "I have noticed that it executes either CST timezone schedulers or "UTC" timezone scheduler. i.e. job B runs every day" isn't very clear.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I have just updated my description. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: That's still not nearly as clear as if you could give examples of what *does* happen vs what you *expected* to happen. When the jobs do run, do they run when you expect them to?

Comment: @JonSkeet - Job should run as it's scheduled time. But It's not. Say, when Job A should run 6 am UTC and Job B should run on Sunday 1st March at 4 am CST (10 am UTC) then only Job A runs but Job B not.

Comment: So do they *never* run, or do they run at the wrong time? All of this information should be in your question.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Either CST time zone schedulers (Job B and Job C) runs or Job A runs when they have same day to run (As I have mentioned in description).

Comment: I don't see anything like that in the description - and it's still basically hard to follow what you're seeing. Simply listing the dates/times that you're actually seeing the jobs running and when you expected them to run (in the question, not in comments) would make it *much* clearer.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Sorry for inconvenience.I have updated description.

Comment: So job b never, ever, ever runs? Or just not every day?

Comment: @JonSkeet - I found that when Job B executes then Job A wasn't and if Job A executes then Job b wasn't executes. It's happens on every Sunday.

Comment: Right, that's all information which you should put in the post, *very clearly*... e.g. in a table of what you've observed when. I'm amazed that I've had to request this information so many times. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints and think about what *you'd* want to see if you were trying to answer the question. Concrete examples really, really help (as does nicely formatted code, btw...)